# Version Comment mandatory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, version-history, version-comments

I have separate document for each department, with versioning enabled, but users do not provide version comment while uploading new version of the document.

I am finding some way to make the **Version comment** mandatory, while uploading document.

How can can I achieve this !

Comment: There is a solution on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715038/sharepoint-2010-document-library-versions-comment) where a user answers this question, but requires code. If that's what you're looking for, it seems to have worked for users.

Comment: Hi @panic , please don't add only link as an answer, please add detail steps and add the URL as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no OOTB way to achieve it. You have to write code (EventReceiver or EventHandler) to achieve it.

There is an another way if you really do not want to write a code, then you can create a custom column Ex- "Version Comment", and set that as Required Column.